# Change datetime format generated with make-series operation in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

**Introduction:**

In Azure Data Explorer there is a make-series-Operator which allow us to create series of specified aggregated values along specified axis.

**Where is the problem:**

The operator works good except the changes in timestamp format.
For example

```
let resolution = 1d;
let timeframe = 3d;
let start_ts = datetime_add('second', offset, ago(timeframe));
let end_ts = datetime_add('second', offset, now());
Table
| make-series max(value) default=0 on timestamp from start_ts to end_ts step resolution by col_1, col_2
```

**Current results:**

I got the result contains the timestamp in UTC like the following

```
"max_value": [
    -2.69,
    -2.79,
    -2.69
],
"timestamp": [
    "2020-03-29T18:01:08.0552135Z",
    "2020-03-30T18:01:08.0552135Z",
    "2020-03-31T18:01:08.0552135Z"
],
```

**Expected result:**

result should be like the following

```
"max_value": [
    -2.69,
    -2.79,
    -2.69
],
"timestamp": [
    "2020-03-29 18:01:08",
    "2020-03-30 18:01:08",
    "2020-03-31 18:01:08"
],
```

**Question:**

is there any way to change the datetime format which generated in make-series operation in kusto to be NOT in UTC format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to change the datetime format which generated in make-series operation in kusto to be NOT in UTC format.

it's not clear what you define as "UTC Format". [Kusto/ADX uses the ISO 8601 standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime), and timestamps are always UTC. You can see that is used in your original message, e.g. `2020-03-29T18:01:08.0552135Z`.

if, for whatever reason, you want to present datetime values in a different format, inside of a dynamic column (array or property bag), you could achieve that using `mv-apply` and `format_datetime()`:

```
print arr = dynamic(
[
    "2020-03-29T18:01:08.0552135Z",
    "2020-03-30T18:01:08.0552135Z",
    "2020-03-31T18:01:08.0552135Z"
])
| mv-apply arr on (
    summarize make_list(format_datetime(todatetime(arr), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
)
```